# Vue cannot bind bus event data and components data

Tags: vue.js, event-bus

```
created() {
  eventBus.$on('replayMail', data => {
    this.newMail = data
  })
}
```

So I am emitting an event bus event to get the data from one component to the other. For some reason, it is not working and the object `newMail` remains empty.

How do you assign data from event bus to the local components data?

If any more code or other info is needed, please let me know.

Comment: who is emitting `replyMail`, and how is your eventBus configured? share as much code as you can.

Comment: make sure your component that listens to the event is in added to the DOM